# install rtmp module on nginx pre-built

Tags: nginx, rtmp

Recently I installed stable version of nginx from nginx.org and configured rtmp module to work with it. After some time I realized that my PHP is not working normal and installed configured PHP with FPM but server was too messy after that. I got another test server from google engine and installed nginx pre-built package from package manager with `apt-get install nginx-full` command, but didn't find any way to use rtmp module with that. As nginx official blog claims that, "not all modules, but some of them, including rtmp module is configurable for pre-built version of nginx". I tried to follow guide below:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-installable-packages-dynamic-modules

But at the end it created another nginx folder on some other location to be used with rtmp module. I tried to include conf file of 2nd nginx to use its rtmp but no luck, I messed everything as I'm net in this industry. Can someone please help me to understand using pre-built nginx with rtmp module? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile the *same version* of nginx as the pre-built while adding the dynamic module, on the same machine or an equivalent one and then copy the resulting module `.so` to the `modules` directory of the pre-built.

You can then load the module by adding:

`load_module modules/some_module.so;`

to the configuration of the pre-built and restarting.

Or you can follow the guide and package it in order to avoid the potential  pitfalls associated with a manual copy. You can do this later once it works after a simple copy.

Comment: Hi @aeegistal, and thanks for reply. I think I started to realize some usage of some directives after your comment. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The idea was great, but I get "ngx_rtmp_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1" error. Both pre-built and downloaded versions are the same and I followed official guide to do it: https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus

Comment: did you set `--with-compat` like `./configure --with-compat  --add-dynamic-module=...` ?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem. nginx 1.12.1 had default configuration issue. Upgraded to 1.12.2 and did everything again, fixed :) Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Tried it, getting `nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5` any idea what might be wrong?